# How to remove the ConsoleLogger programmatically from log4j2?

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I'm having a global logger config that I want to inherit throughout my projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="APP" fileName="/logs/application.logs" filePattern="/logs/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n"/>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="APP" />
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Problem: only in production, I want to remove one of the loggers, the `CONSOLE` appender.

As `log4j2.xml` configuration files do not support conditionals, I thought about removing the console appender programmatically:

```
final LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
final Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
System.out.println(config.getAppenders());
```

Problem: this prints only `{DefaultConsole-2=DefaultConsole-2}`

Question: why can't I see the `APP` or `CONSOLE` appender here? And moreover, how can I remove the console appender then?

Maybe it is possible to **intercept** the log4j context loading somehow, so that I could skip the CONSOLE appender programmatically?

Sidenote: I'm logging as follows, which should in production only go to the `APP` appender, not to console.

```
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
LOGGER.info("test");
```

Comment: Why cannot you just deploy a different logging configuration file for production? The config file location can be changed by system properties, I believe.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to duplicate the log configuration, just for removing the `<AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />` line. As this is just an example, in my real project the logfile is also much more complex. So, regarding future maintenance I'd prefer not having to duplicate the config...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `<ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />` in Console Appender you can add environment variable `<ThresholdFilter level="${CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL}" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />`  or something similar and set this variable to `OFF`. I faces with this problem too and it works for me.

This also works with vm args as follows:

```
<ThresholdFilter level="${sys:console.log.level}" ... />
```

When starting the app: `java -jar -Dconsole.log.level=ERROR`

Sidenote: programatically, removing the console appender would also work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);

    final LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig("loggerName");
    loggerConfig.removeAppender("CONSOLE");
    context.updateLoggers();
}
```

Most important for the programmatic approach is that the `SpringApplication` context must be initialized before! Otherwise the configured loggers are not visible!

Comment: Could I as well change this level programmatically? I'd prefer a spring `@Profile("production")` configuration approach, rather having to set a variable on the target system (that might get forgotten is the system is rebuild).